# Why isn't my background image showing up in CSS?

Tags: css

this is my first posting here and I am new to CSS. I am trying to get a sprite of Mario with dimensions of 32 x 16. When I open the html file nothing appears. I try to inspect element the html but I cannot see a div.

CSS

```css
#stillMario {
    width: 16px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url("sprites/still.png");
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Super Mario</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="stillMario"></div>
        
        <script src="myjs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your console to see if there are any errors (404, etc).  Remove the absolute, left, top and bottom CSS for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<img>` element instead of setting the background of the `<div>`.

Example: `<img src=""sprites/still.png"" alt="Mario" height="32" width="16">`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the folder 'sprites' is in the root of your project, then try prefixing it with '../', then try without the absolute positioning first. If it works, then return the positioning again as follows;

```
#stillMario {
  width: 16px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url("../sprites/still.png");
  //position:absolute;
  //left: 0px;
  //top: 0px;
  //bottom:0px;
}
```

Let me know if it works